# Python way to urlquote "non-standard" parts of url

Tags: python

I have the following url, that I have:

```
https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr. Avila/1/9
```

I would like to encode it so that it looks like a normal url, but is valid. For example:

```
https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr.%20Avila/1/9
```

However, if I use the standard `urllib.quote` it encodes **everything**:

```
>>> urllib.quote('https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr. Avila/1/9')
'https%3A//www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr.%20Avila/1/9'
```

Is there a python method that will encode only the non-standard parts of the url, i.e., excluding the forward slashes and colons, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the 'safe' argument:

If you are on Python3, using `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.parse

x ='https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr. Avila/1/9'
urllib.parse.quote(x, safe = ':/')
```

out:

```
 'https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr.%20Avila/1/9'
```

Answer (score 1):

An example, for Python2

```
In [45]: scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = urllib2.urlparse.urlsplit(url)
In [60]: urllib2.urlparse.urlunsplit([scheme, netloc, urllib.quote(path), query, fragment])
Out[60]: 'https://www.verizon.com/OnDemand/TVShows/TVShowDetails/Sr.%20Avila/1/9'
```

Comment: there is no querystring in my url though?